# ORA-01722: invalid number in to_number

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m trying to connect data from two tables by invoice number,

```
LOC         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)
INV_ORG            NUMBER
```

Like this it works fine:

```
SELECT     oh.inv_org,e.loc
FROM       headers oh, sites e
WHERE
AND e.location = TO_CHAR(oh.inv_org);
```

But when I try to convert char to number I get 
ORA-01722: invalid number

```
SELECT     oh.inv_org, e.loc
FROM       headers oh, sites e
WHERE
AND to_number(e.loc) = oh.inv_org;
```

> Error report
>
> ORA-01722: invalid number

I don't know why because in select, conversion works also fine

```
INV_ORG  110992
LOC  110992
OH.INV_ORG-TO_NUMBER(E.LOC) 0
```

Comment: First things first. One time you're using `sites.location` and the other time you're referring to `sites.loc`. Please clarify this. If conversion `to_number` fails it means you have a value in your column which is not a number. You're only showing us 1 row of data. Aren't there more? Also, do not use old syntax of implicit JOINs, use the JOIN keyword instead to connect data from tables.

Comment: both are `loc` I have shortened for clarity. I've showed only one row but it doesn't matter I've tried on bigger set of rows.

Comment: using join doesn't help, same situation as above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your data, it's possible to have a value in `e.loc` cannot be converted to number.

By the way, below select gave ORA-01722:

`SELECT to_number('test') FROM dual`

Comment: Already found two. But exporting to excel. Is there possibility to check such thing with query?

Comment: You may try this code in Oracle to be sure the string is numeric or not:
LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(string1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Comment: I will suggest `to_number(trim(' test'))` . This was post here [to_number function return Invalid number](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2378457). Solve my problem when I was using `SUBSTR` before the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

If this doesn't work:

```
SELECT     oh.inv_org, e.loc
FROM       headers oh, sites e
WHERE
AND to_number(e.loc) = oh.inv_org;
```

it means that there are `e.loc` values that can't be converted to numbers (such as letters). Therefore, you should use query which *works* (as there's no problem in converting `oh.inv_org` to a string):

```
SELECT     oh.inv_org,e.loc
FROM       headers oh, sites e
WHERE
AND e.location = TO_CHAR(oh.inv_org);
```

**However**, the whole story means that current data model isn't correctly set. Columns you are joining *might* need to be used in a foreign key constraint of some kind, i.e.

- there should be a table that contains locations,
- it should have a primary key, and
- that primary key column should be referenced from both headers and sites tables.

If that was the case, you wouldn't have problems you have now.

P.S. Oh, yes - and, try to switch to ANSI joins; won't fix your current problems, but will pay off in the future.

```
SELECT oh.inv_org,e.loc
FROM   headers oh join sites e on e.location = to_char(oh.inv_org);
```

Comment: You are right but it's not my base.
I found two loc: test_loc, test_loc2
which aren't numbers. I will deocde them or stay with to_char

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes number-type attributes are created in the database as `VARCHAR` type. Then they try to be converted to number, be it using the function `TO_NUMBER()` or for example `Integer.parseInt(String a)` in Java code. Reasons for this could be many. The problem comes when the data to be persisted in that field is not validated before persisting. Then when you try to apply, for example `MAX(TO_NUMBER(e.loc))`, you get an `ORA-01722: invalid number error` as the title indicates. As suggest by @Adrian Tufa, the problem possibly is with the already persisted data in that column.

One approach to fix this is to try to find those rows that contain not only numbers, specifically digits from 0 to 9. This can be done with the function `REGEXP_LIKE()`. Once you find the conflicting rows, you can just change their values so you can be sure no rows exist that contain non-digit only characters.

Be it the table name **site** as **e**, and the attribute **loc**:

```
SELECT * FROM site e WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(e.loc,'\D+');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM site e WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(e.loc,'[^0-9]+');
```

Once you find the conflicting rows, you remove all non-digit characters from column loc in their rows respectively and you can try to treat this field as number again.

**Advice**: Some people recommend no to declare a field as a VARCHAR if you plan to using it as a number type. Specially if you don't implement proper validation mechanisms before persisting data in that table.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: to_number function takes 2 parameters

```
SELECT     oh.inv_org, e.loc
FROM       headers oh, sites e
WHERE
 to_number(e.loc,'9999999') = oh.inv_org;
```

Comment: Second parameter is optional and I've tried it before result: ORA-01722: invalid number